# Show image inside modal, Even if it's the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a file `input` that allows me to upload an image, After selecting an image the modal is opened with the image inside the modal.

Here is a [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dt53fL7q/14):

Here is the code:

```js
$("#input").on("change", function(e) {
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
      file = this.files[0],                   
      image = new Image();
  $('#image').attr('src',  _URL.createObjectURL(file));
  $(image).ready(function($) {
   $('#modal').modal('show');
  });
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Input to upload images -->
<input type="file" id="input" name="image">

<!-- Modal to show uploaded image on -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Image Upload</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Uploaded Image -->
          <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
        </div> <!-- .container -->
      </div> <!-- .modal-body -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
    </div> <!-- .modal-content -->
  </div> <!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- .modal -->
```

But if I close the modal and try to upload the same image it's not opened, As I'm using `change`.

I tried to use `click`:

```
$("#input").on("click", function(e) {});
```

But I get these errors and the modal is not shown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

I will then check the image dimensions and size.

So how to make it work that if I choose the same image again it will be opened?

Comment: is not gonna work with "change" cause the value on your input is not changing when you upload the same file

Comment: @PaolaReyes Yes it will, if you reset it in the change handler once you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reset your `input`'s `val` attribute to an empty string in your `change` event handler.

Your trouble is that the input's `change` event doesn't get called when its `val` attribute doesn't change. Obvious on the face of it, but you're probably confusing your `img` and your `input` elements. Not only do you need to call `revokeObjectURL` to free up browser memory, you also need to reset the value of your `input`. Otherwise, if you open the same file, nothing changes in your `input` element so its `change` event doesn't get called. Revoking the URL in the `img` element is irrelevant to the `input` element.

```js
$("#input").on("change", function(e) {
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
      file = this.files[0],                   
      image = new Image();
  $('#image').attr('src',  _URL.createObjectURL(file));
  $(image).ready(function($) {
   $('#modal').modal('show');
  });
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
  $(e.target.id).val(''); // <- ADD THIS
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Input to upload images -->
<input type="file" id="input" name="image">

<!-- Modal to show uploaded image on -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Image Upload</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Uploaded Image -->
          <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
        </div> <!-- .container -->
      </div> <!-- .modal-body -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
    </div> <!-- .modal-content -->
  </div> <!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- .modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset your input value on click

```js
$("#input").on("change", function(e) {
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
      file = this.files[0],                   
      image = new Image();
  $('#image').attr('src',  _URL.createObjectURL(file));
  $(image).ready(function($) {
   $('#modal').modal('show');
  });
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
});
$("#input").on("click", function(e) {
var value= $('#input').val();
  if(value){
    $('#input').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Input to upload images -->
<input type="file" id="input" name="image">

<!-- Modal to show uploaded image on -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Image Upload</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Uploaded Image -->
          <img id="image" src="" alt="Picture">
        </div> <!-- .container -->
      </div> <!-- .modal-body -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
    </div> <!-- .modal-content -->
  </div> <!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- .modal -->
```

Comment: This works, but adds unnecessary code overhead. You can just add `$('#input').val('');` to the `change` event. This will reset the state of the `input` element to what it was on page load every time the modal is closed.